# Quanto fa puzza?

Tags: verbs, grammar

1a.Quanta puzza fa?

1b.Quanto fa puzza?

2a.Quanto schifo fa?

2b. Quanto fa schifo?

Nel caso della 2a. e 2b. direi che la corretta è la seconda, visto che fare schifo è una locuzione avverbiale.

Quelle che mi lasciano un po' perplesso sono la 1a.  la 1b.

Proprio perché "fare puzza" non è locuzione verbale, poi suona naturale dire "fa molta puzza" il che potrebbe legittimare la 1a.

La 2a.invece starebbe letteralmente per "fa molto puzza/fa puzza molto" che non mi suonano né naturali né corrette.

Comment: Personalmente, ma forse è un fatto regionale, “fa molta puzza” non mi suona particolarmente naturale, e non sono neppure sicuro di cosa intendi: che “c'è molta puzza”, in generale, oppure che una certa cosa “puzza molto”?

Comment: @DaG: la seconda, ovvero che  una cosa puzza eccessivamente

Comment: @DaG È possibile che sia regionale -- a me *fa molta puzza* suona naturale (e *che puzza che fa!* mi suona addirittura più naturale di *quanto puzza!*)

Comment: Capisco. Per curiosità, il Treccani, per esempio non lo riporta sotto i sinonimi di [puzzare](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/puzzare_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/), dove pure sono riportati vari termini regionali (e il fatto che sia una polirematica non è un problema: sotto “fingere” c'è anche “fare finta”). D'altro canto i dizionari non sono onniscienti.

Comment: «Nel caso della 2a. e 2b. direi che la corretta è la seconda, visto che fare schifo è una locuzione avverbiale.» Non direi che ci sia una versione corretta ed un no; a mio avviso sono entrambe perfettamente accettabili e la prima, anteponendo "schifo", enfatizza il concetto. Lo stesso discorso vale per "*Quanta puzza fa puzza*" / "*Quanto fa puzza*" (o anche solo "*Quanto puzza*")

Answer (score 2):

Utilizzare `fare` con `puzza` può essere una locuzione dialettale, ma non è la forma preferibile in Italiano per il semplice fatto che esiste un verbo appropriato (`puzzare`) che si può usare al suo posto.

Osserviamo i seguenti punti:

1. `Puzzare` è un verbo intransitivo.
2. `Fare` è un verbo transitivo e intransitivo.

Le frasi con il verbo `Puzzare` possono pertanto avere solo forma attiva, per esempio `quanto puzza?`. Questa locuzione è da preferire all'utilizzo del verbo `fare` (`quanta puzza fa`) per il motivo che quest'ultima forma è completamente equivalente alla prima in termini di informazione, ma utilizza un verbo generico invece che il verbo `puzzare`, che è disponibile e più diretto. In generale, si può dire che *è più corretto* utilizzare il verbo appropriato, se disponibile, invece che crearne una con verbo generico + sostantivo (`puzza`).
Se usassimo altri verbi più specifici invece di `fare`, ad esempio:

- quanta puzza `emette`?
- quanta puzza `sprigiona`?
- quanta puzza `è percepibile`?
  qualificheremmo la domanda con una sottigliezza che fornisce più informazioni, quindi questa forma sarebbe più accettabile.

Riguardo l'esempio con `schifo`, gli esempi citati sono completamente equivalenti, cambia solo l'ordine delle parole.

Answer (score 0):

Sia 1a che 1b suonano molto male. Direi che la versione giusta è:

1c. Quanto puzza?

Quanto a 2a e 2b, le ritengo valide entrambe, ma penso che 2a sia più usato al Sud e 2b al Nord.

Se dico "quanto schifo fa?", allora "quanto" è un aggettivo.

Se dico "quanto fa schifo?", allora "quanto" è un avverbio.